# How to tell checker that a legacy method will accept Nullable types?

Tags: java, checker-framework

Consider this:

```
@Nullable Object obj = null;
Optional<Object> optional = Optional.ofNullable(obj);
```

This fails because checker-framework assumes `ofNullable` cannot accept `null` values (after all, its parameter is not marked as @Nullable).

Is there a good way to tell checker-framework that this method (or other methods in legacy code that I cannot change), accepts @Nullable types everywhere without having to change code everywhere?

Comment: This seems to be a current limitation of the framework. The solution, in my view, is to allow custom configuration to add the type annotations to external libraries (in my opinion, the default of assuming everything non-null is just fine), including the Java SDK. For example, let me add to a config file the following declaration: "<T> Optional<T> java.util.Optional.ofNullable(@Nullable T t)" which will "override" the actual definition. Of course, it should just add Type annotations, not change them or mess with return/parameter types.

Comment: This would remove the need to have an "annotated JDK" and make it possible to add annotations to any library.

Comment: It's not a current limitation of the framework because the feature you propose already exists and is called [stub classes](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#stub).  It can be used in conjunction with the annotated JDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: this answer was based on @mernst help in the comments and in the [Checker Framework's Issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/checker-framework/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=12)

If you, like me, do not want or cannot use the annotated JDK, you will run into this issue.

*Note: In most Java shops I've worked, we simply cannot switch which compiler we use or provide a "custom" JDK (that's really unthinkable). For that to be portable, I would have to add the custom JDK to my source repository, for starters, or distribute it to every machine, including CI servers, where the code compiles, and make sure they are in the exact same path across different OS's. Just not cool.*

The solution is to provide [stub classes](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#annotating-libraries) and pass them as an argument to the `javac` process.

This can be done quite easily with whatever tool you use to compile.

For example, with Maven (using the standard [compiler plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html)):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <annotationProcessors>
            <annotationProcessor>org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.NullnessChecker</annotationProcessor>
         </annotationProcessors>
         <compilerArgs>
             <arg>-Astubs=checkerframework/stubs</arg>
             <arg>-AstubWarnIfNotFound</arg>
         </compilerArgs>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

You also need to add these dependencies to your project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>checker-qual</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>checker</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

Here, `checkerframework/stubs` is a directory (relative to the location of the pom), containing the *stubs*. For Optional, my stub looks like this (strangely, stubs must be named *.astub, so this file is called Optional.astub):

```
package java.util;

import org.checkerframework.checker.interning.qual.*;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

class Optional<T> {
    static <T> Optional<T> ofNullable(@Nullable T value);

    @Nullable T orElse(@Nullable T other);
}
```

This approach is simple, requires little work, does not mess with which compiler I use or the Java libraries at all, makes sure these definitions are only used with the checkerframework (so I can, for example, add this to a Maven profile and enable it only if I want to by simply passing a Maven argument), will work across machines and OS's without previous setup in the true Java way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you say "its parameter is not marked as @Nullable".
When I look at file
checker-framework/checker/jdk/nullness/src/java/util/Optional.java,
I see the following annotated method:

```
public static <T> Optional<@NonNull T> ofNullable(@Nullable T value) {
    return value == null ? empty() : of(value);
}
```

Furthermore, when I run the Checker Framework on the following code, it issues no warning.

```
// run like this:
// javacheck -g TestOptional.java -processor nullness

import java.util.*;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull;

public class TestOptional {

  void m() {

    @Nullable Object obj = null;
    Optional<Object> optional1 = Optional.ofNullable(obj);

  }

}
```

I'm not sure what is going on in your case because you didn't provide a complete test case, you didn't say what command you ran, and you didn't give an actual error message.  (You did provide a diagnosis, but I'm not sure it is accurate.)

Maybe providing more details would enable better understanding of your problem.

Comment: You made the assumption I am using the annotated JDK, which  I am not and I mentioned that in the comments. Knowing that, nothing else is relevant. I am running the NullnessChecker as a simple annotation processor (in Maven but that's not relevant). Using the annotated JDK is definitely not possible (it is not portable, it might cause compatibility/security issues, it even seems completely redundant given the possibility to provide stub classes - maybe you should have the stubs for Jdk8 added by default and eliminate the annotated JDK).

Comment: Furthermore, your answer does not address my more general question: "Is there a good way to tell checker-framework that this method (or other methods in legacy code that I cannot change)...".

Comment: Oh, you are not using the annotated JDK.  You didn't say that in comments or elsewhere.  Why not use it?  That would be an easy way to address your problem.  Regarding annotating legacy code, my initial comment already directed you to the manual's discussion of [stub classes](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#stub).  I see that you have now repeated that in your answer (but without giving credit to my comment).  Anyway, I'm glad that you now understand.

Comment: I explained in my answer's note why I cannot use the annotated JDK. I agree I should have made it clearer I was not using it. I will add credit to your comment in my answer, sorry about that. Great work with this framework, by the way! I hope to be able to contribute to making it even better.

Comment: I am using the annotatedJDK, and I'm still getting compiler errors on some methods where null is a perfectly acceptable value. Is there a place to suggest additions to the stubs file?

Comment: To suggest an addition to a stub file, open an [issue](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/issues) or a [pull request](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/pulls).